# Integrate $\int \frac{2x+7}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across this question in a book - and I've been trying to solve it.
I am only familiar with the integration using standard formulae, substitution and by parts. I'm not familiar with the other methods yet - so please show me a way to solve it using the above methods.

My work:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to substitute a function or simplify the equation in any way.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: I mean the first one  - at least that's the question in the book

Comment: @labbhattacharjee has a good pointer to partial fraction decomposition which makes any rational function (division between two polynomials) nice to integrate.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: @MrYouMath I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Thank you for the comment. I will try to remember this :).

Answer (score 4):

Using partial fractions, you can decompose the integrand into

$$ \frac{2x+7}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1} $$

which gives
$$ \begin{align} 
2x+7 &= A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1) \\ &= (A+B)x^2 + (B+C)x + (A+C) 
\end{align} $$

Comparing coefficients gives 
$$ A+B = 0 \\ B+C = 2 \\ A+C = 7 $$

solving the above system we obtain $A = \frac52, \ B = -\frac52, C = \frac92$

Integrating
$$ \begin{align} 
\int \frac{2x+7}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}dx &= \frac52\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx - \frac52\int \frac{x}{x^2+1} + \frac92 \int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= \color{blue}{\frac52\ln|x+1| - \frac54 \ln|x^2+1| + \frac92 \arctan x + C} 
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

Just an observation on the fastest way to calculate the coefficients in the partial fractions decomposition: the linear system deduced from
$$2x+7 = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x +1)\tag{1}$$
is comparatively simple, but may be longer to solve if there are more terms. A fast way, if irreducible factors are simple (i.e. without an exponent) consists in successively giving $x$  the values of the `poles` of the fraction.

Here we would have:

- $x=-1$, so that $(1)$ becomes
  $$5= A\cdot 2+(B+C)\cdot0=2A,\enspace\text{whence }\quad A= \frac52.$$
- $x=i$: $(1)$ becomes
  $$2i+7= A\cdot0+(Bi+C)(i+1)=(B+C)i+C-B,$$
  whence $$\begin{cases}\phantom{-}B+C=2\\-B+C=7\end{cases}\iff B=-\frac52,\enspace C= \frac92.$$

If  the denominator of the fraction has a multiple irreducible factor, say $P^r$ ($r>1$),  the partial fractions decomposition has $r$ terms
$$\frac{A_1}P+\dots+ \frac{A_r}{P^r}\qquad (\deg A_i<\deg P), $$
and the above method only yields $A_r$. For the other coefficients, you will have to give $x$ other values and solve a (smaller) linear system. In case $r$ is ‘big’ (say $r>3$), resorting to polynomial division `by increasing powers` may be faster.